# How to let an authenticated user like a blog post in Django, update the like count and change the color of the heart icon

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I started building my first Django Project a few days ago and I've been making progress, but for the past two days I've been stuck with the problem stated in the post's title. I can't seem to implement the like functionality in my web application.

I'm going to just post the parts of my code that I believe would be helpful in aiding me.

so, in my **models.py** I have -

```
class Post(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts', default='uncategorized')
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

in my **views.py** I have -

```
@login_required
def like_post(request, post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            post.likes.remove(request.user)
            post.like_count -= 1
        else:
            post.likes.add(request.user)
            post.like_count += 1
            like = Like(user=request.user, post=post)
            like.save()
        post.save()
        return JsonResponse({'like_count': post.like_count})
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

in my **urls.py** I have -

`path('like_post/<int:post_id>/', views.like_post, name='like_post')`

in my **post_list.html** I have -

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'article:like_post' post.pk %}">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <button class="like-button" data-post-id="{{ post.id }}"><i class="fas fa-heart{% if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists %} liked{% endif %}"></i>{{ post.like_count }}</button>
                  {% endif %}
                <button class="comment-button"><i class="fa-solid fa-comment"></i>5 comments</button>
                </form>
```

underneath the **post_list.html**, after all the other html elements, I have -

```
<script>
   $('.like-button').click(function(){
    var button = $(this)
    var postId = button.data('post-id')
    $.ajax({
      url: '/like_post/' + postId + '/',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
      success: function(response){
        button.children('.like-count').text(response.like_count)
        button.children('i.fa-heart').toggleClass('liked')
      }
    })
   })
</script>
```

but, I get an error -

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /
Could not parse the remainder: '(id=request.user.id).exists' from 'post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists'
```

the highlighted area throwing the error is shown as -

```
<button class="like-button" data-post-id="{{ post.id }}"><i class="fas fa-heart***{% if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists %}*** liked{% endif %}"></i>{{ post.like_count }}</button>
```

what to do? I've reached the limits of my understanding of Django to fix the problem by my self.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`length`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#length) template filter as:

```html
{% if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id)|length > 0 %} liked{% endif %}
```